# relative position browser differences, absolute works but has no flow

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to make a shopping cart layout and am having a hard time getting the checkboxes to appear at the right spot. The code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/35Hkj/1/

renders wrong on jsfiddle itself and internet explorer/firefox... It looks right in expression web 4 and chromium. Should be a checkbox beside each color.

If I position one check box with absolute in a relative container it works on all browsers perfectly but loses the flow meaning it doesn't expand the div container dynamically.

Is there a way to position absolute (relative to the parent) without losing the flow??
I'm guessing slicing up the image with css and positioning a checkbox beside each sliced part wouldn't be correct or easy.

Answer (score 1):

Position absolute will allways "lose the flow".

However, you can position the divs absolutely, if they are in the same container as the image. Just change the `left` value accordingly. The container will be strechted to image's height as the image will remain in the flow.

Comment: You should set a fixed width. If you're not ok with that, you will have to use javascript to calculate the width.

Comment: Tho there's a way if you set the divs to display normally as blocks and give them proper `padding`s (eventhough different for each one, it shouldn't be a pain since you calculate `top` anyway, which you wouldn't have to). Hope you got the point. If not, comment.

Comment: Use `static` position and `padding` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the texts beside checkboxes in a label. More semantic + container divs will have enough height to not lose the flow so that you can absolutely position the checkboxes within.

Answer (score 0):

An element with `position:absolute` is always taken out of the regular flow of relative elements.

What you could do is use a sprite for the background image. Place your checkboxes and your image in `float:left` and `float:right` divs or float both of them left and keep a margin between them and modify the background position of the sprite. If you wanted to, you could also use images, though I feel that using a sprite would be faster. For eg.

```
<div>
    <div class='item'>
        <div class='image'>
            <img alt="" src="http://www.ahornblume.ch/images/img1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class='checkbox'>
            <input name="product1[]" type="checkbox" value="skin" />skin
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <div class='image'>
            <img alt="" src="http://www.ahornblume.ch/images/img2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class='checkbox'>
            <input name="product1[]" type="checkbox" value="face" />face
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.item{
    float:left;
    width:auto;
}

.image{
    float:left;
    width:auto;
}

.checkbox{
    float:right;
    width:auto;
}
```

If you wanted to use sprites, you could give each div an `id` and define a background position, depending on the image-checkbox pairing.